# Azure FTP - Access controller

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I have uploaded an MVC project to Azure websites. But I do not have access to the source code anymore.

When I FTP to the azure websites, I can download only the HTML part of it, and not the server side code (controllers). To be specific I am only given access to wwwroot folder.

How can I access the entire project through FTP?

Answer (score 0):

The Controllers are in the wwwroot folder as well. The code of the controllers though is compiled into the bin folder. You cannot get the source code from the FTP.

Comment: Is there any other way of accessing the source code for controllers?

Comment: Unless you don't have it, the only way is to use a tool like ILSpy or .NET Reflector but it won't be exactly the same if it uses Tasks, async or any parallel programming. You will need to modify it to make it readable.